# setting array object value from string reference in jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, object

I have:

```
var objarray = ...
function path(path) {
    obj = this;
    var parts = path.split('.');
    while(parts.length) {
        obj = obj[parts.shift()]
    };
    return obj;
}
```

using some arbitrary array of objects. I want to set the value of an object value using a string as reference.

something like:

```
objarray.item.item.path("item.price") = 12.45;
```

Comment: @tvanfosson sorry I edited to hopefully explain better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this, you can't set a return value as it is your local copy.
If it's mutable you can change it but setting it will only change your local, temporary, variable.

The closes you can do is `objectarray.item.item.path['item.price'] = 12.45` which would be modification of a mutable object.

Comment: in your example is "path" not an element of the array? in my case it is a function

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm saying, it can't be done your way, it can only be solved if `path` was an object in the right most `item`

Comment: If you return a reference to a mutable object you can do it, like this: `objectarray.item.item.path('item.price').value = 12.45`